# Passing return values from a function to bindParam in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

`bindParam()` doesn't seem to evaluate a function and then bind its return value to the parameter of the prepared statement, like so

```
$stmt->bindParam('foo', bar());
```

So, in order to get around this, is it good practice to do this instead?

```
$stmt->bindParam('foo', eval(bar()));
```

Or is there something else someone out there can recommend doing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use [`bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead of `bindParam()`, it can pass values as well:

```
$stmt->bindValue('foo', bar());
```